# Is it possible to modify let bindings?

Tags: variables, clojure, let

I want to find out how to change the value of a variable declared within a let binding of a Clojure function. Below is the code that I'm using. I want the function to return java.lang.String object, which holds the text contained in the String.

```
(defn read-text-from-file
  {:doc "fn read-text-from-file is used to output in \"string\"
format the text in a file."}
  [#^String file-name]
  (let [buff-reader (open-file-reader file-name)]
  (loop [full-text "" line (.readLine buff-reader)]
    (when line
      (-> full-text (.concat line))
;      (println full-text)
      (recur (-> file-name (.concat line)) (.readLine buff-reader))))))
```

**Note**: The function 'open-file-reader' is below:

```
(defn open-file-reader
  {:doc "This is used to open a file, ready for reading"}
  [file-name]
  (let [file-object (java.io.File. file-name)
        buff-reader (-> file-object (java.io.FileReader.)
                        (java.io.BufferedReader.))]
    buff-reader))
```

Comment: What part of the thing you're trying to accomplish requires changing a let binding?

Answer (score 8):

The bindings in `let` are immutable and cannot be rebound. Even if you could rebind them, your problem lies elsewhere in your code. What you need to do is use the `if` special form instead of the `when` macro. With an `if` you can return `full-text` when [`line` is null](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29), and `recur` when it isn't.

---

Although, I suggest you check out the [`slurp`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/slurp) function, which can do all this for you.

```
user=> (doc slurp)
-------------------------
clojure.core/slurp
([f & opts])
  Opens a reader on f and reads all its contents, returning a string.
  See clojure.java.io/reader for a complete list of supported arguments.
nil
```

---

If you still wish to implement this function yourself, I suggest that you at least make `full-text` a StringBuilder. Then you can convert it to a String by saying `(str full-text)`, when you ultimately return it. However, Maurice Reeves provides a more idiomatic Clojure solution in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10658645/160811).

Answer (score 4):

let bindings, like function arguments, are immutable, so you can't change their value.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot mutate the bindings from let.  Just not possible.  What you're trying to accomplish can be done with slurp as mentioned by others, but if you want to go the route you're going, it is possible to return the contents of a buffered-read using a combination of line-seq and apply as seen below:

```
(defn fetch-file-text [file-name]
     (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader file-name)]
          (apply str (line-seq rdr))))
```

You can read more about line-seq here: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/line-seq

And more about apply here:
http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/apply